# meaning of the phrase "last time out" in context

Tags: meaning

Here it goes in context: "The boxer was fined for his words last time out." Does it mean the boxer was not allowed to box in the ring?

Answer (score 2):

I think that "last time out" probably means "on his most recent appearance"
and he was fined on that occasion, perhaps for being abusive. The sentence is not a model of clarity.